# Use Items from listbox in function C#

Tags: c#

I have listed all the directories in a listbox.

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      listBox3.Items.Clear();
      string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\test");

      foreach (string dir in dirs)
      {
        listBox3.Items.Add(dir);
      }
}
```

I need to perform a function with all listbox items. Like this

```
Listbox.Items = foo;
encrypt(foo);
```

I've tried in many ways but I did not get anything.

Always returns an error that can not convert the Items from listbox to a string. How I do it?

I am working on a school project, the teacher told us to create something to do with privacy, I am working on a SHA256 encryption algorithm with AES algorithm, the program user chooses a folder that wants to keep anonymous, choose a passowrd and encrypt the Folder, and just with the same password can decrypt the folder, my program is not very well done, if I just select a folder it only encrypts the files that are in that folder and nothing more, but conventionally someone who wants to encrypt their Files are because they have many and are probably organized into folders, hence my question, I need the program to list all folders and subfolders and there encrypts the files one by one.

Comment: What is `foo`?  What is `function`?  The error is telling you that you're using the wrong type.  So what types are you using and what types are expected?

Comment: Would probably help us help you if you told us what the function is going to do.

Comment: are you trying to convert all of the items within the listbox, or just the one that's currently selected?

Comment: I'm trying convert all items, and already edit my question.

Comment: when you write *Listbox.Items = foo;* ,do you mean *var foo = Listbox.Items;* ? otherwise *encrypt(foo)* doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Remove `foreach` loop. Use data binding: `listBox3.DataSource = dirs;`

Comment: I meant to say encrypt(foo), I thought it going to encrypt(Listbox.Items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the items from your `ListBox` as a list of strings using the `Cast` method (which requires Linq: `using System.Linq;`). Then you can pass them to a method that can process them:

```
List<string> directoryPaths = listBox3.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

// Assuming you have a method that takes a list of strings:
EncryptDirectories(directoryPaths);
```

The method above takes a `List<string>`, which in this case is all the items in your listbox. It could then go through each item in the list and encrypt them one by one. In this example, it's passing each item to another method that does the actual encryption of a single directory:

```
// Encrypts all files in all the directories (and their sub directories)
private static void EncryptDirectories(List<string> directoryPaths)
{
    if (directoryPaths == null) return;

    foreach (var directoryPath in directoryPaths)
    {
        EncryptDirectoryFiles(new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath));
    }
}

// Encrypts all files in the specified directory and it's sub directories
private static void EncryptDirectoryFiles(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    if (directory == null) return;

    if (directory.Exists)
    {
        foreach (var file in directory.EnumerateFiles())
        {
            // Pseudo encryption of file by adding an unknown extension
            File.Move(file.FullName, file.FullName + ".encrypted");
        }

        // Recursively process any sub-directories
        foreach(var subDirectory in directory.EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            EncryptDirectoryFiles(subDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: retorned me this, It's not possible to convert "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" to "string"

Comment: Nowhere in my sample did I try to convert the `List<string>` to a `string`. What does the line of code look like that's giving you that exception? I've updated the answer with an actual sample implementation of the encryption methods. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: Wow thanks! This really helps me a lot! I've been working on this for weeks and never thought of it that way, if you do not mind a last question: how can I list the encrypted files for another listbox? Thanks again

Comment: nevermind, I found a way, anyways thank you for your time, I will put Rufus L in credits of my program.

Comment: @IloveCode If this solves your problem then please mark as solution